# How can I take a picture at 50mm with a Finepix s8200?

Tags: focal-length, zoom, fujifilm

I have this camera. How do I take a picture at 50mm with zoom lens?
Does this camera support zoom lens at 50mm?

Comment: Maybe explaining _why_ you need a picture at exactly 50mm would be of interest here? Usually unless you are trying to replicate an example photo, using a specific focal length isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The Fuji FinePix S8200 is a superzoom bridge camera with a zoom lens that yields a *Field of View (FoV)* equivalent to a 24-960mm lens mounted on a 35mm format camera. To get a *FoV* equivalent to 50mm on a 35mm format camera you would need to set the S8200 to about 9mm. There is no obvious indicator in the display when zooming, though. Here is an easy way to get fairly close:

- Zoom all the way out. That puts you at about a 24mm *FoV*.
- Take note of an object that is about halfway between the center and the side of the view finder.
- While keeping the camera pointed in the same direction, zoom in until the object you just noted is now on the edge of the frame. You should be at roughly a 50mm *FoV*.
- Take note of where this is on the zoom indicator scale displayed in the viewfinder during zooming.

If you need to be more precise than that, take a look at the EXIF data from a photo you take when zoomed in as described above. Most compacts will give both the actual focal length the shot was taken at as well as the 35mm equivalent in the EXIF data. Using the number in the EXIF data, make an adjustment and shoot again until you find the spot that yields a 50mm focal length in the EXIF data and note where the line was in your zoom indicator when you took that photo.

Answer (score 1):

When you zoom, you will see some numbers on the lens: Read them carefully! It says on the left side and right side:

```
LEFT SIDE             RIGHT SIDE
equiv.135

80mm                  14.4mm
135                   24.4mm
200                   35.9mm
300                   53.9mm
500                   89.8mm
830                   149.1mm
```

Comment: What is the Right side ? Is it the 50mm equivalent (so the 50mm is about 292mm) ?

Answer (score 0):

The finepix s8200 has a 4.3mm - 172.2mm lens that is equivalent to 24 - 960mm on a full frame.  It may not have a way to set a particular focal length though, but you might be able to find out from the EXIF data in the files it saves if the camera bothers to write out the focal length.

In general, point and shoots aren't often concerned enough with control to tell you the actual focal length you are shooting at.